# How to rename some files according to their timestamp

Tags: powershell, rename, timestamp

suppose I have 10 files generated by the system every day under D:\Temp. The names are RANDOMLY when generated.

Assume I need to rename the oldest one to be 'aaa', the second oldest one to be 'bbb'..then 'ccc'...'ddd'.

can someone help to write batch script? Powershell cmdlt will be good as well.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', etc, do you mean that literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using a list of names:

```
$names = @('one.txt', 'two.txt', 'three.txt', 'four.txt', 'five.txt', 'six.txt', 'seven.txt', 'eight.txt', 'nine.txt', 'ten.txt')
$count = 0
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem i:\temp | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 10)){
    Rename-Item $file.FullName (Join-Path $file.DirectoryName $names[$count])
    $count++
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!It comes in handy for someone like me who almost know nothing about powershell / batch scripting

Answer (score 0):

It would matter how you want to name them. Using something like 1,2,3,4 is easiest. You would need to declare the variable for the name and an incrementer. Although that is relatively easy and straight forward. For the finding the order of creation:

```
Get-ChildItem h:\CallCList | Sort-Object CreationTime |`
    ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item $_.Name -NewName $NameToUse
    }
```

That would be the work of the it for finding and renaming.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would rename them to some strings which are already set, I will declare the variable for them:)