# How to rename files based on timestamp, with batch script?

Tags: windows, batch, rename, timestamp

Suppose I have 10 files generated by the system every day under D:\Temp. The names are RANDOMLY generated.

Assume I need to rename the oldest one to be 'aaa', the second oldest one to be 'bbb', then 'ccc', 'ddd' and so on.

assume these are the target names I will use:

```
Beijing
shanghai
hangzhou
suzhou
newyork
lanzhou
huzhou
guangzhou
tianjin
sichuang
```

Can someone help with a batch script to accomplish this?

*I actually asked this question [yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/595900/how-to-rename-some-files-according-to-their-timestamp) and was given a wonderful answer using PowerShell, but today I notice in company's VM I don't have PowerShell installed (not allowed to install by yourself), so need to post question again so that people who already answered can retain their (accept) votes.*

Comment: Does it have to be batch? Can you use any portable GUI renaming programs?

Comment: yes it has to be batch. Can't use any GUI tool as it's a team-shared server and takes a long procedure to install anything there

Comment: Ella, please **register your account** here. You seem to keep losing your cookie, and you should edit your original question or leave comments rather than posting answers below. See http://superuser.com/help/user-merge for more.

Comment: If you need the creation date, you should show your date format, the output of `dir /a-d`.

Comment: hi slhck, have registered. Should be working fine now. Thanks for remindering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file1=aaa"
set "file2=bbb"
set "file3=ccc"
set "file4=ddd"
set "file5=eee"
set "file6=fff"
set "file7=ggg"
set "file8=hhh"
set "file9=iii"
set "file10=jjj"

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%A in (
  'wmic datafile where "drive='d:' and path='\\temp\\'" get creationDate^, name ^| findstr "^[0-9]" ^| sort ^| findstr /n "^"'
) do for /f "delims=" %%F in ("%%C") do (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%N in ("!file%%A!") do (
    endlocal
    ren "%%F" %%N
  )
)
```

If you want to change the path, then you must be sure to double up all `\` as `\\` and make sure the path starts and ends with `\\`. The appropriate drive letter (with colon) must appear in the drive option.

Both the drive and path values must be enclosed in single quotes - WMIC uses SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks dbenham, but when I change the path in your script and run it i get 'Description = Invalid query" error code.

Here is the script after I changed it. May looks silly but i'm almost totally new to scripting.

I also noticed you set "chars= abcdefghij", but what if I need to rename the 10 files differently? Say here are target file names, from oldest to newest ones:

    Beijing
    shanghai
    hangzhou
    suzhou
    newyork
    lanzhou
    huzhou
    guangzhou
    tianjin
    sichuang

Comment: @ella - You should be more precice with your questions. I've updated the answer to facillitate setting of any target names. You should be able to specify any valid drive and path. Just be sure the syntax is as I've outlined above. If you still have problems, then you should provide the specific path that is not working.

Comment: ，thanks for the help. I'll try again when i get office today.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. It renames 26 files to `aaa` to `zzz`, oldest creation date first. Look at the output and remove the `echo` command, if it is OK.

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "startfolder=D:\temp"
set "alphas=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
cd /d "%startfolder%"

set /a counter=0
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('dir /a-d /od /tc ^| findstr "^[0-9]"') do set "fname=%%b"&call:process
goto:eof

:process    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "nname=!alphas:~%counter%,1!!alphas:~%counter%,1!!alphas:~%counter%,1!"
if not defined nname goto:eof
echo rename "%fname%" "!nname!"
endlocal
set /a counter+=1
goto:eof
```

If your `dir` command showes the time with AM/PM, set `tokens=4*`.

Comment: thanks and sorry I have not put it clearly. When I say 'aaa','bbb','ccc',,,i didn't literally mean that. let's assume the target names are : Beijing
shanghai
hangzhou
suzhou
newyork
lanzhou
huzhou
guangzhou
tianjin
sichuang

Comment: oh, I see. In this case you should make a new question.